# How can i pass 'n' number of requests based on value extracted from json path extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

In Jmeter, I have extracted a value from json. The value is 2. My requirement is I need to send following HTTP samplers.
Here it is 2.
So I need to send the following 2 http requests.
http://IP:PORT/users/0?authSSOId
http://IP:PORT/users/1?authSSOId

If its 'n' request I need to pass upto 'n' counts in the url
How can i Achieve this

Answer (score 2):

You can add loop controller which will execute HTTP request as per your extracted count. Structure will look like below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Still its not working. url only fetches value which extracted from json. ie 2

Comment: Please add counter under the loop controller and give following values: Start=0, Increment=1,Maximum=${count},reference name=c1 and then change http request url as http://IP:PORT/users/${c1}?authSSOId

Comment: Please mark my answer accordingly...http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Given you have this `2` living in a JMeter Variable, i.e. `${valueFromJson}`

1. Add [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) to your Test Plan and put the following expression into the "Condition" input:

   ```
   ${__javaScript(${counter} < ${valueFromJson},)}
   ```
2. Put a [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) as a child of the While Controller and configure it like:

   - Start: `1`
   - Increment: `1`
   - Reference Name: `counter`
3. Put your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler after the Counter

The HTTP Request will be executed as many times as the `${valueFromJson}` variable value

[image: JMeter While Controller Counter]

Comment: I am afraid, its not working. Still the url only passes '2' instead of 0, 1                                    exp output: http://10.18.0.239:8081/users/0?authSSOId
                   http://10.18.0.239:8081/users/1?authSSOId                                                  act output: http://10.18.0.239:8081/users/2?authSSOId